# Launching The package installer

Tags: android

I'm looking for a way to automatically start the android Package Installer , after the browser finishes downloading an apk file . Any  ideas on this ? Currently after the download  is over the list of downloaded files is displayed and clicking on the downloaded apk launches the Package installer . (step which I'd like to automatize)

I've thought on launching the instalation manually with code like this :

```
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/downloadedApk"),
"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

,but I'm unable to find when the download completes to execute the snipet above.

Comment: are you able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "automatically start the android Package Installer , after the browser finishes downloading an apk file" -- sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Uri uri = Uri.fromParts ( "package", "abc", null);

rtn = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED, uri);